# Merge AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 application contexts:

```
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(BeansConfig.class);
```

and

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext secContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring-security.xml");
```

How can I make these into a single context without re-writing the XML with annotations or vice versa ?

```
   ApplicationContext mergedContext = // appContext.merge(secContext ) ????
```

Is something like this possible ?

Comment: Put `@ImportResource("classpath:"/META-INF/spring-security.xml")` on your `BeansConfig`... But why are you creating your own configuration? Generally that is something you shouldn't be doing and an indication that you are doing the wrong things. (That configuration should be loaded by either a `ContextLoaderLIstener` or `DispatcherServlet`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Configuration class to import both xml and annotation config

```
@Configuration
@Import(BeansConfig.class)
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-security.xml")
public class AppConfig{}
```

You can also add this directly on Spring Boot Main Class if you use Spring boot